# Autofill Service via Flutter and Kotlin like a Password-Manager

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, passwords, autofill

I am currently working on the **Flutter App** which acts similarly to a **Password Manager** and consists of basic features such as **saving passwords** and **using them** in another app, **For ex:** let's say I saved my account detail for google in my app including (Mail and Password) then I go to google app and try to login but at that time my app will suggest me my saved username and password so I can just autofill my way out of this easily!

I am planning to implement this using **Autofill Service or Framework** from **Kotlin** but I am kinda confused on the logic part, let's say I have Username and Password ready to be passed to my Kotlin file via **MethodChannel** like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "saveUsernamePass"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            val username = call.argument<String>("username")
            val password = call.argument<String>("password")
            // This method is invoked on the main thread.
            if (call.method == "executeKotlinCode") {

                // Execute the desired Kotlin code with the received parameters
                requestAutofill(username, password)

                // Return a result if needed
                result.success("Kotlin code executed successfully")
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestAutofill(username: String?, password: String?) {
        MyAutofillService.username = username
        MyAutofillService.password = password
    }
}

class MyAutofillService : AutofillService() {
    companion object {
        var username: String? = null
        var password: String? = null
    }

    override fun onFillRequest(
        request: FillRequest,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
        callback: FillCallback
    ) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSaveRequest(request: SaveRequest, callback: SaveCallback) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Now what do I need to do further like with the logic? All I know is that **onSaveRequest** saves the user's data and **onFillRequest** can fill the user's data in textfield on behalf of the user...

Would really really appreciate your help here.